# ngrx-json-apiの使い方

Tags: angularjs, redux, angular5

Angularを3日勉強しているものです。
プログラミンの基礎知識はあります。

Angular5系 + ngrxを利用したサンプルアプリケーションを作成しています。
その際、ngrx-json-apiというライブラリを利用するのですが
使い方がよくわかりません。
https://github.com/abdulhaq-e/ngrx-json-api

githubに載っている情報を元にコードを書いているのですが、
ブラウザ上ではメソッドがないとうエラーなどを吐いてしまいます。

Getting Started以下を
1-5までやったのですが以下の部分でエラーを吐いています。

```
let zone = this.ngrxJsonApiService.getZone(NGRX_JSON_API_DEFAULT_ZONE);
// => getZoneが定義されていない。
// this.ngrxJsonApiServiceにそのメソッドはあるはずです。importが間違っているのか？


this.queryResult = this.selectManyResults(newQuery.queryId, denormalise);
// => newQueryは初めて出てきているので、なぜ変数などの定義もなしにいきなり出てきているのか理解ができない。

const query: Query = {
      queryId: 'myQuery',
      type: 'projects',
      // id: '12' => add to query single item
      params: {
        fields: ['name'],
        include: ['tasks'],
        page: {
          offset: 20,
          limit: 10
        },
        sorting: {
          { api: 'name', direction: Direction.ASC }
        },
        filtering: {
          { path: 'name', operator: 'EQ', value: 'John' }
        }
      }    
    };
// => 型のQueryは初めて出てきてますよね・・・理解ができない
```

---

モジュールのimport周りや、ngrxの仕組みを理解できておらず
ライブラリを正しく扱えていないと予想しておりますが
ライブラリをインストールできていない、ライブラリの依存性の問題、などなど
他にも原因としてあげられることはあります。

実は早急にサンプルアプリケーションを作成しなければならない状況にあり
angular, ngrxの理解もかいつまみながらやっております。
そのため、理解していない部分が多くあるかもしれません。
情報は随時追記していきます。

どなたか知見ある方がいらっしゃいましたら
ご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 出来れば単に「エラーが出ました」だけではなく、「実際に表示されたエラーメッセージ」を質問に含めた方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/127850